# Possible to use COUNTIF with a function on the range's values?

Tags: excel, anonymous-function, countif

Let's say that I have a list of dates starting from A1 and going across...

`1/3/2014`
`2/5/2014`
`5/5/2015`
`8/10/2016`
`...`

I'd like to count the number of times a certain month appears in this range.  My current solution is that the row below it just contains `=MONTH(x1)`, where `x` is the column, and then I call a COUNTIF on that row.

I don't think that's so bad of a solution, but it does require a whole bunch of extra cells just to calculate months in my spreadsheet, which isn't really necessary for anything else.

So basically, is there any way to do something along the lines of =COUNTIF(MONTH(range),5) to count, for example, the number of times something occurs in May?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't do that, `COUNTIF` function requires a range as first argument - any operation on a range (like using `MONTH` function) converts that range to an array that `COUNTIF` doesn't accept

Possible alternative are to use `SUMPRODUCT` e.g.

`=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(range)=5)+0)`

or `COUNTIFS` like this

`=COUNTIFS(range,">="&Z1,range,"<"&EOMONTH(Z1,0)+1)`

where Z1 is 1st of the month to count, e.g. 1-May-2013

Of course the SUMPRODUCT version doesn't take account of the year (although you could add that in) while COUNTIFS does

**Explanation**

In `SUMPRODUCT` when you use an expression like `MONTH(range)=5` that returns an "array" of `TRUE/FALSE` values like `{TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE}`....but `SUMPRODUCT` here only sums numbers so we need a way to "co-erce" TRUE to 1 and FALSE to 0. You can do that with any mathematical operation that doesn't change the value, e.g. +0, *1 or you can add -- to the front like this:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(range)=5))`

so we get something like

`=SUMPRODUCT(--({TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE}))`

...and that becomes

`=SUMPRODUCT({1;0;0;1})`

and then SUMPRODUCT sums those values to get 2, i.e. the number of dates in May.

SUMPRODUCT is preferred to `SUM` purely because you don't need to "array enter" the formula with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

See [here](http://www.xldynamic.com/source/xld.SUMPRODUCT.html) for a good explanation of SUMPRODUCT and it's many uses

Comment: I was going to suggest an array formula but sumproduct is much better.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it makes sense in general, but could you explain why that "+0" is necessary at the end of your SUMPRODUCT function?  My guess is that it's something along the lines of forcing it into the type (int) that you want.  Is that correct, or something else?

Comment: +0 in this context "coerces" a TRUE/FALSE value to a 1/0 value because SUMPRODUCT only deals with numbers - I provided a more detailed explanation in my answer.