# Select Range of Dates that match Month and Type

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I have a range of Dates:

```
--ID------Date-----Type
 123  |10/27/2013|  1
 124  |11/27/2013|  2
 125  |12/27/2013|  3
 ...      ...      ...
```

And I need to select the Sum of all Type "1" items that are have a date in October.
I tried reiterating through each:

```
For i = 7 To tmRowCount
    If (person.Cells(i, "D").Value = ctype) Then
        cmth = Month(person.Cells(i, "C").Value)
            If cmth = mth Then
                c = c + 1
            End If
    End If
Next i
```

But its very slow and won't work great once I get a large number of entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(A2:A10)=10)+0, (B2:B10=1)+0)
```

Here `A2:A10` is the range containing dates to look for, `B2:B10` is the Type column.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478714/possible-to-use-countif-with-a-function-on-the-ranges-values) for detailed explanation

Comment: Perfect, Thank you: `Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(" & Chr(39) & person.Name & Chr(39) & "!C7:C1000)=" & mth & ")+0, (" & Chr(39) & person.Name & Chr(39) & "!D7:D1000=" & Chr(34) & ctype & Chr(34) & ")+0)")`

Answer (score 0):

You also can try to use `.Find` combined with`.FindNext` to locate filter criteria. I find this method faster than doing a full loop most of the times.